# Check if first letters of consecutive words in string match acronym of another string

Tags: python, regex, match

Say I have a list and a string:

```
l=['hello my name is michael',
'hello michael is my name',
'hello michaela is my name',
'hello my name is michelle',
'hello i'm Michael',
'hello my lastname is michael',
'hello michael',
'hello my name is michael brown']

s="hello my name is michael"
```

Internally, I want to search for each word in the string and count how many times each word from this string appears in each list element.

```
hello my name is michael: 5
hello michael is my name: 5 (all words are present)
hello michaela is my name: 5 (extra characters at end of word are Ok)
hello my name is michelle: 4 
hello i'm Michael: 2 
hello my lastname is michael: 4 (extra characters are end of word are not Ok) 
hello michael: 2
hello my name is michael brown: 5
```

Finally, I wish to return all matches in the order of the highest count items first. So the output would be:

```
hello my name is michael: 5
hello michael is my name: 5
hello michaela is my name: 5
hello my name is michael brown: 5
hello my name is michelle: 4 
hello my lastname is michael: 4
hello i'm Michael: 2 
hello michael: 2
```

This is essentially a regex matching and sorting problem, but I am over my head on this one. Any advice how to proceed with any or all of the steps?

Comment: You need to provide a mininal working example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which you attempted in order for us to help you.

Comment: So, I'll give you some pointers. 1. You don't need regex for this. ; 2. From your string use `split()` ; 3. Create a function that initializes a counter variable ; 4. For every term in the `split()` like `for i in range(len(s.split()):` rummage through the array of strings using `ii` so you embed `for ii in range(len(l))` and search `if s.split()[i] in l[ii]: counter += 1`  Yaddda, Yadda

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your expected output. Do you mean like this:

```
import re

l = ['hello my name is michael',
    'hello michael is my names',
    'hello michaela is my name',
    'hello my name is michelle',
    'hello i am Michael',
    'hello my lastname is michael',
    'hello michael',
    'hello my name is michael brown']

s = "Hello my name is Michael"

s = s.lower().split()
for item in l:
    d = item.lower().split()
    count = 0
    for ss in s:
        try:
            if ss in d or re.search(ss+"\w+",item.lower()).group() in d:
                count += 1
        except:
            pass
    print (item, count)
```